# in my Signed apk not showing google map , need step by step process

Tags: android, google-maps, release, signed-apk

I already released my app on play store, Now i am going to add google map into that app.

So for that i created app key for Google map Api. I placed it into 
" app/src/debug/res/values/google_maps_api.xml " file & AndroidManifest.xml .

While testing on emulator and mobile device app showns google map but after signed apk generated and that signed apk didn't show map.

Plz give me step by step process (i checked other  ans  but didn't helped me ):

Comment: What & All posts you have gone through so far?

Comment: Check @Daniel answer [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32544737/google-maps-are-not-showing-in-signed-apk).

Comment: you need to add your release SHA1 in the api console....

Comment: Thanks you all , yes just added release SHA into api console , now its working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your release **signed SHA-1 key** and **debug SHA-1 key** are different. When you were developing your project you created your maps credentials using **debug SHA-key** so you should create your **credentials** using **release SHA-1 key** to work it on release version. Take more reference from here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31800728/3863689

Comment: Thank you so much. I got SHA key  and added to same key at api console.
Now it works. I was confused ,  previously i created another key with SHA   and that was using in my proj.